# .net core not routing to POST method

Tags: c#, http-post, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Link to project here -> https://github.com/crumdev/hqbbq.git

I have a simple 3 page MVC website with 1 controller. For the contact page I have a small 3 input form. Below are the Controller methods:

```
[Route("contact/")]
public IActionResult Contact()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Contact(string name, string email, string message)
{
    ViewBag.Name = name;
    ViewBag.Email = email;
    ViewBag.Message = message;

    return View();
}
```

When I submit the form with a breakpoint inside of the Contact method for HttpPost it never breaks but instead uses the regular method and just returns the view again. I have tried reducing my form to just the name field and only capture that and it does not enter the POST method. I have given the regular Contact method the [HttpGet] attribute so it can only be used strictly for GET requests and when I submit the form then it bypasses my controller altogether and returns the Dev exception page that is blank except for "Hello World!" on the screen. I have read through the documentation and followed tutorials on teamtreehouse.com for regular ASP.Net as well but cannot understand why it is behaving this way.

Edit:
Here is the code for the page submitting the POST. I am just using a plain HTML form with the POST method for submitting the data.

https://github.com/crumdev/hqbbq/blob/master/HQ-BBQ/Views/Home/contact.cshtml

Comment: Without the client code that is presenting this behavior, we cannot help you. (i.e post your javascript/ajax/html form)

Comment: you dont give any route to your post method ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The POST action needs to have a route as well if the intention is to use attribute routing.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("contact")]
public IActionResult Contact() {
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("contact")]    
public IActionResult Contact(string name, string email, string message) {
    ViewBag.Name = name;
    ViewBag.Email = email;
    ViewBag.Message = message;

    return View();
}
```

Note the exclusion of the slashes as they are not needed. Make sure the names and ids of the form inputs match the parameters of the target action

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem. If I had a separate ContactController would I have needed to explicitly have the routes above the methods for this still?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing the `Route` attribute on the `[HttpPost]` method.
Try this.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("contact/")]
public IActionResult Contact(string name, string email, string message)
```

Also update your view code, so that the `name` property of your `<input />` tags matches the arguments of your controller action.

Remember that MVC uses the name property to bind to the arguments in your controller action.  [MSDN Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

For example update your email input to include the name property:

```
<input name="email" id="email" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Email" value="@ViewBag.Email">
```

You'll also need to update the text area name to `name="message"`.

Comment: THANKS. but now  respose returned from 404 to     **: (415) Unsupported Media Type.** its better than nothing. but still doesnt reach the controller

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FromForm annotation for your parameters in the controller post method

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("contact")]
public IActionResult Contact([FromForm]string name, [FromForm]string email, [FromForm]string message)
```

I would also recommend to use a viewmodel rather than passing all the fields of your form as parameters. Imagine you have a form with 10 fields, your method signature would be a way harder to read

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't route to action because i passed object not matched to model, for instance

```
public class NewsModel : IActive
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string NewsName { get; set; }
    public string NewsText { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }}

{"id":0,"newsName":"123","newsText":"123","active":""}
```

active - should be boolean, but i passed string.
So first thing one have to do is to remove parameters in Post methods.

```
[HttpPost]   public async Task<IActionResult> PostNews(  )
```

If now you get in action, so you have problem in model, otherwise - you have problem in routing